# How create a GIN index on nested arrays in PostgeSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with column "data" of jsonb type. The structure looks like this (synthetic simplified example):

```
[
  {
    "object": "car",
    "fields": [
      { "id": "price", "value": "200000" },
      { "id": "weight", "value": "600" },
      { "id": "color", "value": "green" }
    ]
  },

  {
    "object": "wheel1",
    "fields": [
      { "id": "diameter", "value": "16" },
      { "id": "height", "value": "20" }
    ]
  },

  {
    "object": "wheel2",
    "fields": [
      { "id": "diameter", "value": "17" },
      { "id": "height", "value": "30" }
    ]
  }
]
```

The goal is to find rows which has objects with some field properties like so:

```
SELECT * FROM cars
WHERE data @> '[{"fields": [{"id":"diameter", "value":"16"}, {"id":"height", "value":"20"}]}]'
AND data @> '[{"fields": [{"id":"price", "value":"200000"}, {"id":"weight", "value":"600"}]}]';
```

EXPLAIN of course says that Seq Scan is involved. I know how to create GIN index on objects in array:

```
CREATE INDEX cars_data_idx ON cars USING gin ((data->'some_array') jsonb_path_ops);
```

However I'm unable to create a proper index on "fields" arrays, which are in objects inside main array. Is it generally possible? What is the correct syntax for that?

Comment: No. You index the *whole* `jsonb` column to support these queries.

Comment: You might be able to build an index on the expression `(SELECT jsonb_agg(o->'fields') FROM jsonb_array_elements(data) o)`, but that would mean you'd also have to rewrite your query to `WHERE (SELECT jsonb_agg(o->'fields') FROM jsonb_array_elements(data) o) @> '[[{"id":"diameter", "value":"16"}, {"id":"height", "value":"20"}], [{"id":"price", "value":"200000"}, {"id":"weight", "value":"600"}]]'`. I'm not sure if this even works (you'd have to try), but the query is unwieldy enough to probably not be worth the effort, unless you can save a huge amount of data to index.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks a lot. I thought such approach would not work. But it works :)